# ios 14: [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios14, xcode12

I'm receiving a message in the log saying

```
[general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release.
```

I have recently downloaded `iOS14` on my Mac. I'm developing some login page in the project. It's working fine on `iOS13` and lower versions. But on `iOS14` I'm getting the above issue. User interaction not there on the login page.

On `iOS14` I am trying to enter the `username` and `password` I can't able to enter. user interaction is not there. I am using objective-c.

Anybody help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning suggests, `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` will be removed in the future because it's not secure by default.

If you are using `CoreData` then you have to update your `CoreData` Structure accordingly to save your data.

**Checkout following thread:**
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107533

**Edit:**

If you are not able to enter a username or password on your Simulator, then Disable the `Automatically Sync Pasteboard` option on your Simulator and relaunch the Simulator.

**Steps:**

- Go to Simulator
- Click On Edit
- Uncheck Automatically Sync Pasteboard
- Relaunch the Simulator

Comment: thanks for your response bro. can you please create a chat room please. i want to chat with you. i have some doubts

Comment: I can't do that here. Pls, add your query here.

Comment: in this perticular page iam not using any core data. i am saving user id and password in NSUserdefaults.

Comment: NSUserdefaults are not a secure way to store Username and Password. Please use `Keychain` to store sensitive information.

Comment: today production is there. so i cant able to change the code. any temporary solutions please let me know. please create chat room bro. i have many doubts

Comment: Connect me on LinkedIn /in/milanpanchal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222067/discussion-between-satyam-and-milanpanchal).